# Как переделать код JQuery с использованием метода .each()?

Tags: jquery, html

Здравствуйте!

Написал вот такой вод код:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var flag = true;
    var countLabels = $(".labels a").size();
    var hiddenBlockWrapp = "<span class='hiddenBlock labelsHiddenBlock'></span>";
    if(countLabels >= 5){
        var countHiddEl = countLabels - 5;
        $(".labels a:nth-last-child(-n+"+countHiddEl+")").wrapAll(hiddenBlockWrapp);
        $(".labels a:nth-child(24)").after('&nbsp;<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="toggleLabels icon-arrow-down"></a>');
        $(".toggleLabels").live("click", function(){
            flag = !flag;
            if(flag){
                $(this).remove();
                $(".labels a:nth-child(24)").after('&nbsp;<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="toggleLabels icon-arrow-down"></a>');
            }else{
                $(this).remove();
                $(".labels a:last-child").after('&nbsp;<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="toggleLabels icon-arrow-up"></a>');
            }
            $(".labelsHiddenBlock").slideToggle();
        });
    }
});
```

-

```
<div class="labels">метки: 
    <a class="blue under" href="javascript:void(0)">мотоцикл</a> 
    <a class="blue under" href="javascript:void(0)">море</a> 
    <a class="blue under" href="javascript:void(0)">дорога</a>
    <a class="blue under" href="javascript:void(0)">мотоцикл</a> 
    <a class="blue under" href="javascript:void(0)">море</a> 
    <a class="blue under" href="javascript:void(0)">дорога</a>
    <a class="blue under" href="javascript:void(0)">мотоцикл</a> 
    <a class="blue under" href="javascript:void(0)">море</a> 
    <a class="blue under" href="javascript:void(0)">дорога</a>
</div>
```

Отображаются эти метки списком (в строку). Проблема заключается в том, что на странице с одним .labels работает идеально, если таких элементов больше, то работает, мягко говоря, не верно. Есть понимание, что нужно JQuery код нужно переписать с использованием метода .eeach(), но, к сожалению, у меня знаний что-то не хватает((((

Comment: А если своими словами, то какой результат вы хотите получить?

Comment: есть список меток, нужно что бы отображались первые, скажем, пять, а остальные отображались по клику на ссылку.
Сейчас у меня скрипт определяет количество меток, заворачивает все кроме 5 первых в блок, после по клику этот блок либо показываю, либо скрываю

Comment: Понятно, что ничего не понятно. Уточняем дальше ))

> а остальные отображались по клику на ссылку.

У вас их в примере 9 шт. На какую именно?

Comment: ссылка добавляется динамично
<pre><code>$(".labels a:nth-child(24)").after('&nbsp;<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="toggleLabels icon-arrow-down"></a>');
</code></pre>

Comment: вот ссылка на код http://jsfiddle.net/TakT/5SZsD/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё равно не уверен, что понял правильно, но посмотрите [этот вариант](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/geMFC/)

Comment: Блин идеально))
Спасибо!!!

Comment: Кстати, только заметил ваш предпоследний комментарий, [вот маленькая поправка](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/5SZsD/1/)

Comment: спасибо, по гуглил - смысл понял!

Comment: вопрос все же еще открыт
При одном блоке с ссылками работает идеально, но если их больше то нет!
http://jsfiddle.net/TakT/QHtkB/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var visibleCount = 5;

    var area = $("<span />").css('display', 'none').appendTo($(".labels"));
    $(".labels a").each(function(i,el){
        if(i >= visibleCount){
            $(el).remove();
            area.append(el).append(" ");
        }
    });

    var flag = false;
    $("<a />", {href: '#', html:'...'}).click(function(){
        $(area).css('display', (flag ? 'none' : 'inline'));
        flag = !flag ;
    }).appendTo($(".labels"));
});
```

Comment: работает с Вашим html-каркасом

Comment: Ваш вариант как и предыдущий работает не правильно, если блоков .labels больше одного, он раскрывает сразу все имеющиеся такие элементы на странице

Comment: переделал первоначальный предложенный вариант
http://jsfiddle.net/TakT/QHtkB/2/

Comment: ну вот и молодец! :) все сам сделал )

Comment: ))) всем спасибо!))

Answer (score 0):

вот эта ссылка http://jsfiddle.net/TakT/QHtkB/3/